# Wait until all other coroutines are blocked?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-asyncio

I'm trying to test asynchronous communication. The protocol for exchanging secure messages is:

1. Send the message asking the other side for NONCE
2. Wait for the response until timeout
3. Send an encrypted message using the received NONCE

While the following code works in production, it's a real pain to test:

```
import asyncio
import pytest

messages = []
async def send_request(message):
    global messages
    messages.append(message)

class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nonce = asyncio.Future()
    def send_message(self, message):
        asyncio.create_task(send_request(message))
    def send_get_nonce(self):
        self.send_message("NONCE_GET")
    def receive_nonce(self, nonce):
        self.nonce.set_result(nonce)
    def send_encrypted_message(self):
        asyncio.create_task(self.send_encrypted_message_impl())
    async def send_encrypted_message_impl(self):
        self.send_get_nonce()
        nonce = await asyncio.wait_for(self.nonce, 3)
        self.send_message(f"ENCRYPTED_MESSAGE {nonce}")

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_communication():
    global messages

    node = Node()

    node.send_encrypted_message()
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    assert messages.pop() == "NONCE_GET"

    node.receive_nonce(123)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    assert messages.pop() == "ENCRYPTED_MESSAGE 123"
```

Evety time I create a task, I need to yield from the test body to run it. Is there a way to avoid multiple `await asyncio.sleep(0)` calls? I want at most 1 such call.

I would prefer to keep the `Node`'s interface non `async`, because secure communication is only a part of `Node`'s behavior and most other use cases are a simple synchronous request-response exchange. Secure communication is an exception to this and doesn't warrant propagating async to all other components in my opinion.

I'm still new to coroutines, so maybe my entire approach to the problem is flawed and there is a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure you're getting anything from making the interface non-async, because the caller still has to run inside an event loop. The proper way to wait for the message to appear is to use an `asyncio.Event` which you set in `send_request` after appending the message. Then you can just `await` that event in `test_communication`.

Comment: @user4815162342 By not making the interface async I'm saving myself from having to `awat` every single call in the chain. And thanks for reminding me about `Event` - it's exactly what I was looking for!